# Text mining with pandas: how do I transform the column of my reviews into string?

Tags: python, pandas, text

I am working on a text mining project with a given dataset that has x restaurants and for each one it has different variables.
Among these there are reviews. Reviews are written this way in a list.

So if I have 2 reviews per restaurant, for example, I have:

`[['Great Experience'],['felt like home']]`

This is creating problems because I want to apply a function that applies only to strings so I need the brackets gone or I just need the words ( I don't care about distinguishing review 1 from review 2, I just need the words) and I need to do it for the whole column.

What do you guys suggest to do?

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like the values themselves already are strings?

Comment: No. Every restaurant's review column is made of a list of lists containing the reviews. So like [["great experience"],["lovely"]] so python doesn't see this as strings.  I tried to work with the functors.reduce function but I feel like there must be an easier way

Answer (score 0):

You can flat your list first:

```
original_list = [['Great Experience'], ['felt like home']]
flat_list = [elem for sublist in original_list for elem in sublist]
```

And then apply your method to `flat_list`.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly, you simply need to get a list of strings instead of a list of lists.
I've provided two solutions, but they're pretty much the same thing:.
Suppose the function simply prints the string passed as an argument:

```
def my_func(review):
    # do something
    print(review)
```

Suppose this is your column from the dataframe (i.e. list of lists):

```
lst = [['review 1'], ['review 2'], ['review 3']]
```

## 1st approach - pass the indexed list of lists.

```
for i in lst:
    my_func(i[0])
```

## 2nd approach - convert single-list elements to strings:

```
reviews = [i[0] for i in lst]
for i in reviews:
    my_func(i)
```

The output from both approaches is identical:

```
review 1
review 2
review 3
```

edit: typos.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def join(row):
    return " ".join(j for i in row for j in i)


df = pd.DataFrame({
    "rest": ["x", "y"],
    "review": [[['Great Experience'],['felt like home']], [['Great Experience'],['felt like home'], ['qwerty']]]
})

df["result"] = df["review"].apply(join)
```

---

```
    rest    review                                              result
0   x   [['Great Experience'], ['felt like home']]              Great Experience felt like home
1   y   [['Great Experience'], ['felt like home'], ['qwerty']]  Great Experience felt like home qwerty
```

---

Now, once the `df["result"]` is a string, you can apply your function.